# How do I customize 'type' attribute to javascript_tag helper in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, handlebars.js

How do I add a custom `type` attribute to a `javascript_tag` helper in Rails?

```
<%= javascript_tag id: 'entry-template', type: 'text/x-handlebars-template' do %>
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The above returns:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/javascript">
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

The desired output is:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: very good question. I looked at the source for [javascript_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag) and it seems to use [ŧag_options](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/tag_options), but I couldn't find a reason for why the `:type` is automatically set at all. Perhaps the documentation is out of date.

Comment: PS: Just use the html version for now. It's shorter anyways :P

Comment: Thanks for your input. The finicky nature of the 'javascript_tag' helper is indeed quite curious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javascript_tag` is for, um, JavaScript, it says so right in the name. If you want to use a `<script>` as a container for something that isn't JavaScript, just write it by hand:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    alert('All is not good');
</script>
```

or, if you must use a helper, use `content_tag`:

```
<%= content_tag(:script, :id => 'entry-template', :type => 'text/x-handlebars-template') do %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

I don't see the point to using `content_tag` for this though, just seems to over-complicate things.

Comment: Your banter is somewhat justified due to the vagueness of my question. I suppose my want for the helper all comes down to uniformity with the other devs I'm working with. The content tag will do fine. Thank you.

Comment: You could add your own `handlebars_tag` helper if you wanted. That would give you some symmetry with `javascript_tag` and help ensure that you had consistent `type` attributes. There's also a gem for precompiling all your Handlebars templates that might be of interest: https://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets

Comment: I will definitely look into both of your suggestions! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<%= javascript_tag :html_options => {id => 'entry-template', :type => 'text/x-handlebars-template'} do %>
    ------------------------
    ----------------------- 
<%end%>
```

May it would work. I have not tried it.